# How can I estimate the inductance of an inductor operating at different frequencies than the test frequency?

Tags: inductor

I am looking for a 10uH inductor to operate under 200kHz. [I found this inductor, but its test frequency is 100kHz instead.](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/SRP1038A-100M/4876659)

How can I determine if it's ok to use this inductor? Is there a way to estimate the inductance when it's operating at different frequencies?

I can't find a recommended range of frequencies to use this inductor anywhere in the datasheet.

Comment: For greetings and thanks, please see [Expected Behaviour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) on chit chat.

Comment: (FWIW, resonance frequency is 10 MHz. Have an eye on temperature rise, you may need to derate current.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, inductor properties change gradually with frequency.  You are very unlikely to find a problem over such a small difference in frequency.

Or put another way, any inductor that changes aggressively, so close to its rated frequency, isn't a good inductor to begin with.  (Now, whether they're selling it as an inductor regardless of that -- well, that's another issue.)

Depending on what you're doing with them, though, you may still have problems.

---

First, regarding frequency range.

The SRP1038A family isn't terribly well specified.  The best data they provide are linked from the product page, 
[AEC-Q200 Compliant Electronic Components | Bourns Power Inductors](https://bourns.com/products/magnetic-products/power-inductors-aec-q200-compliant/product/SRP1038A) 
which offers a spreadsheet containing these parameters:

[image: SRP1038A parameter spreadsheet]

This low-order<sup>[1]</sup> model has few degrees of freedom, so probably won't be very accurate.  At best it can exhibit a single self-resonant mode, and will have Q most accurate at whatever point it's calculated around.  But it will not be accurate over a wide range of frequencies -- certainly not from DC to SRF.

To be clear, this is not a physical model of the inductor -- it's just a bunch of calculated parameters.  We can still associate them with physical aspects: Rser is the winding DC resistance; L is the overall inductance; Rp is core loss (imagine the core as an array of very small shorted turns coupled to the inductor<sup>[2]</sup>); and Cp is the winding capacitance (anywhere we have two conductors, there is capacitance between them -- even if they're two ends of the same piece of metal, as in a winding).

The provided model however doesn't seem to fit the measured parameters.  I get a Q factor of 204, not 20, at 100 kHz.  So, for our purposes, we can discard these data as *meaningless*.  That's unfortunate, but shows the reality of the market: manufacturers are under no obligation to give anything more than what they're selling.  (My guess is, at best, they fit parameters to the SRF peak; but the resistance (Rp) even then seems very unrealistic.  That or they made a typo in the datasheet and meant 200 Q instead of 20, but needless to say, I wouldn't stake a design on that.)

Since we can't rely on better measurements or modeling provided by the manufacturer, we are left to our assumptions, and what little is in the datasheet.

We can generally assume a reasonably-straight impedance around the test frequency (i.e., \$|Z| \cong 2 \pi f L\$), leveling out to DCR at low frequencies, and peaking and then falling back down at the SRF.  (10 µH at 10 MHz implies a peak in the ballpark of 630 Ω, but it can be higher or lower depending on actual core losses.)  That is, from about 1 kHz to a bit under 10 MHz, we should expect reasonably-inductive behavior.

Over the inductive range, Q factor also cannot change very quickly.  For instance, for air-core inductors, it varies typically as \$\sim \sqrt{f}\$.  At 200 kHz, we expect no more than \$20 \sqrt{\frac{200k}{100k}}\$ or 28, and based on my experience with similar materials, I would guess it's instead lower than 20, not higher.  Maybe 15-18.

(It's worth noting that the datasheet only specifies *minimum* Q, so it could be any number higher than that.  But if they could specify more, they would; I would guess the actual value is not much higher than given here, perhaps 21-23 typical.)

[1] Just as we can fit a polynomial curve to a data series, we can fit a schematic to an impedance curve.  A lumped-element (RLC) circuit is in fact a graphical representation of a rational polynomial; to which we can always add more elements to raise the order and improve accuracy.  Containing one L and one C, this is a 2nd-order fit, and so is only correct at, at most, four points.

[2] The datasheet notes they use "carbonyl iron", a form of iron powder that is commonly used for inductors.  The analogy of "small shorted turns" is quite apt here: eddy currents flow around the microscopic iron particles (or between, where they touch).  This material has the downside that, when packed densely (to give high permeability, that is, high inductance for a given shape, size and number of turns), it also has high losses (lots of particles are touching).  And this is borne out by the datasheet, with no parts in the family offering a Q above 20.

---

Second, regarding use.

As a use was not suggested, I'll go through a typical example of a buck converter application.  This is a common enough application to be representative, and demanding enough to illustrate the limitations of a part like this.  Less demanding applications, like EMI filtering, will be much less sensitive to core losses; though the loss, and capacitance, will affect the damping and RFI response of the filter.

For a buck converter, we apply a square wave voltage to one side of the inductor (we can ignore voltage ripple on the other side), and get a triangular current waveform through it.  The product of these (square times triangle) gives the reactive power flowing through the inductor.  Thus, the reactive power is related to the current ripple.  Which is in turn related to the output (DC) current by the ripple fraction, RF = Ipk / Idc.

Q factor is defined as the ratio of reactive to real power, so for a given reactive power, we divide it by Q to get real inductor loss.  Mind this is in addition to DC loss (given by DC resistance, 27 mΩ for this part).

The maximum power rating of this part is apparently 1.5 W (it's rated 7.5 A at 40°C temp rise).  If we were delivering just DC, this would be a sufficient rating, but if we must also account for AC losses, we must derate Idc accordingly.

If we assume half core losses, then 0.75 W, or 15 VA reactive, should be the typical capacity of this inductor.  (This requires derating current to 5.3 A or less.)

Now we come to a problem: the reactive power of a nonsinusoidal wave isn't well-defined, and Q isn't constant with frequency anyway.  We can take waves *specific to this application* (square wave voltage, triangle wave current), and come up with a solution.  Keep in mind this is not a general result, but only applies for this case.  We can also just wave our hands and assume Q is constant -- it won't be, but the harmonics of these waveforms drop off quickly as well, so we're probably only incurring a few percent of error by doing this, even if Q drops to 1 or less at some point.

That said, for a 50% square wave of \$\pm \frac{V_{in}}{2}\$ applied to an inductor, we expect a ripple current of \$I_{pk} = \frac{V_{in}}{8 L f_{sw}}\$.  The product of which dissipates an average power of:<sup>[3]</sup>
$$ P_L = \frac{2 {V_{in}}^2}{\pi^2 Q L f_{sw}} $$

Inputting the 0.75 W from before, and the component parameters and \$f_{sw}\$, we get \$V_{in}\$ about 12 V, implying about 6 V output, and given the 5 A RMS rating, around 30 W.  Which corresponds to a 15% ripple fraction (implying VAR = \$\frac{5}{3} V_{in} I_{pk}\$), which suggests an average current mode controller will be required (peak mode controllers are mode common, but unsuitable for such low ripple fractions due to the nature of the control scheme; constant-on-time or other types may also be suitable).

[3] I've omitted a small correction factor that arises from the waveforms:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^3} = \frac{7 \zeta(3)}{8} \approx 1.0518\ldots $$
The (2n+1) is simply the odd harmonics of the waves, which go as 1/n (n odd) for square and 1/n<sup>2</sup> for triangle, hence the cube product.  This factor depends on duty cycle; this is only for the special case at 50% duty.

Comment: "...that changes aggressively, so close to its rated frequency, isn't a good inductor..." or at least it's poorly rated, or even deliberately deceptively rated.